# multiple strings to variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to assign multiple string values that can be possible to a variable. It can be either of the 3 values that gets stored in the variable(NOT more than 1 for but could be any of the 3).
I have the below CASE inside a stored procedure to assign as such :-

```
flag_one := 
            CASE 
            WHEN flag_one = 'ACH' THEN 'ACHPayment_Confirmed'
            **WHEN flag_one = 'SAMEDAY' THEN 'HIFV5_FTRINF' OR 'HIFV4' OR 'Payment_HIFV5_FTRINF'**
            WHEN flag_one = 'LBX' THEN   'LOCKBOX_CONFIRM'
            WHEN flag_one = 'ELBX' THEN 'eLockbox_Confirmed'
            WHEN flag_one = 'EBPP' THEN 'Transactis_Confirmed'
            WHEN flag_one = 'RDC' THEN 'RDC_Confirmed'
            --ELSE NULL
            END;
```

What is a good way to do that? Compilation error received is PLS-00382:expression is of wrong type.

Comment: Do you want it to just pick one of the three string values at random to store in the variable? Or is there some kind of logical pattern?

Comment: How are you trying to use this? You could pick one of the values and just use that or change the data type from a string to a collection and store all 3 values.

Comment: OK, so suppose entering the CASE expression, `flag_one = 'SAMEDAY'` What should be assigned to `flag_one` in this case? (What should be the value of the CASE expression?) It can't be "this" OR "that" OR "the other", can it? Not unless you have FURTHER conditions: IF "something" THEN "this", ELSE IF "something else" THEN "that", ELSE "the other".

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
random_val := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;

flag_one := CASE flag_one
              WHEN 'ACH' THEN 'ACHPayment_Confirmed'
              WHEN 'SAMEDAY' THEN
                CASE
                  WHEN random_val BETWEEN 0 AND 0.3333333333
                    THEN 'HIFV5_FTRINF'
                  WHEN random_val BETWEEN 0.333333333 AND 0.6666666666
                    THEN 'HIFV4'
                  ELSE 'Payment_HIFV5_FTRINF'
                END
        WHEN 'LBX' THEN   'LOCKBOX_CONFIRM'
        WHEN 'ELBX' THEN 'eLockbox_Confirmed'
        WHEN 'EBPP' THEN 'Transactis_Confirmed'
        WHEN 'RDC' THEN 'RDC_Confirmed'
        --ELSE NULL
        END;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d61804/3)

Best of luck.